# Add Margin to buttons while translating in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, slider, css-animations

I have this custom slider

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-airvm5?file=src/app/app.component.css

On Next and Previous buttons clicks images are getting changes from `images` array but main issue is when we click on next button while translating the next and previous button position are changed to top, but here i want when i translate as different slides will have different height of images so next and previous button should automatically positioned according to the height of images. I was trying to give margin top also

```
 let currentMargin = parseInt(this.nextdiv.nativeElement.style.marginTop);
 if(isNaN(currentMargin)){
    currentMargin = 0;
  }
   
 let newMargin = currentMargin + 70;  
 this.next.nativeElement.style.marginTop = newMargin+'px';
```

> screenshot:

[image]
Any solution Thanks

Comment: move them out of container div https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dargfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @MUsama If some images have more height then while translating will buttons positions get disturbed.

Comment: how about this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dargfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @MUsama Same issue as shown in above screenshot the buttons are misplaced while transition of the slides but i want button should automatically takes the space according to the height of the images

Comment: We need to set min-height for container div, which should be greater than image height and keep the button at the bottom of container div https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dargfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html